# How can I create persistent notifications?

Tags: google-hangouts

Hangouts Chat only seems to create temporary notifications that disappear after about 10 seconds. Is there a way to override this to force persistent notifications that require interaction? Our users simply aren't seeing new messages and therefore Chat is not being used in our organization. I looked into creating a bot to handle this but that doesn't look like it will help since bots only respond when mentioned. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can send asynchronous responses using the REST API. Have you tried this? To use the [Hangouts Chat REST API](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic) you will need to:

1. Create a Cloud Project
2. Create a service account
3. Add the bot to the room
4. use Spaces.messages.create() to create asynchronous notifications

You can also @mention a user by having the bot respond with a text value < user/user_id >. This is referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic)

Ex:

```
{
  "text": "Hello < user/user_id > Please respond to this message"
}
```